# Is there a way to delete document with optimistic lock in spring data cosmos

Tags: spring-data, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-spring-boot

Plain Java Client provide the functionality to update/delete with _etag check for optimistic locking.
Spring data cosmos also provide functionality for optmistic locking in save method with _etag check.
Is there a provision for the same in delete document through _etag check in spring data cosmos.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the delete method will work only with the `@Version String _etag` annotation. Please see the [Spring Data Cosmos SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/cosmos/azure-spring-data-cosmos) for more specific information.

- Supports Optimistic Locking for specific containers, which means upserts/deletes by document will fail with an exception in case the document was modified by another process in the meanwhile. To enable Optimistic Locking for a container, just create a string _etag field and mark it with the @Version annotation. See the following example:

[image]

Please let me know if you have any additional questions.